# Covering all scenarios with if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm doing the below homework exercise:

> Given 2 int values greater than 0, return whichever value is nearest to 21 without going over. Return 0 if they both go over.

I've made the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(blackjack(22,22));
    System.out.println(blackjack(25,25));
    System.out.println(blackjack(19,25));
    System.out.println(blackjack(25,19));
    System.out.println(blackjack(10,10));
    System.out.println(blackjack(19,10));
    System.out.println(blackjack(1,19));
}

// Create a method like:
public static int blackjack(int a, int b) {
    if (a > 21 && b > 21) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a <= 21 || b > 21) {
        return a;
    }
    else if (a > 21 || b <= 21) {
        return b;
    }
    else if (a >= b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

All of it works except the last line of output in my main. I keep getting "a" or, "1" in this case, so I'm not sure what is wrong with my last line in my method declaration. I have a feeling something is wrong but I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: You need to change || to && in - `else if ( a <= 21 || b > 21){` and `else if ( a > 21 || b <= 21){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int blackjack(int a, int b){
    if ( a > 21 && b > 21){
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( a <= 21 && b > 21){
        return a;
    }
    else if ( a > 21 && b <= 21){
        return b;
    }
    else if ( a >= b){
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also avoid some of those if-statements if you instead rely on some mathematical operations:

```
private static final int TARGET = 21;
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println(blackjack(22,22)); //  0
    System.out.println(blackjack(25,25)); //  0
    System.out.println(blackjack(19,25)); // 19
    System.out.println(blackjack(25,19)); // 19
    System.out.println(blackjack(10,10)); // 10
    System.out.println(blackjack(19,10)); // 19
    System.out.println(blackjack(1,19));  // 19
}

public static int blackjack(int a, int b) {
    if ( a > TARGET && b > TARGET) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Math.abs(a - TARGET) < Math.abs(b - TARGET) 
       ? a 
       : b;
}
```

Note: This works here because 21 is nowhere close to the MAX_INT boundary; if it were overflow would be an issue. Here this article, [subtraction is not comparison](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/subtraction-is-not-comparison), for more information if you're interested.

[Working example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/kmtLyK)

Comment: Thanks for this! I would highlight that this method doesn't work when a = 20 and b =  22 though. Upon further testing, I found that when `a < target && b > target` or vice versa, the method returns the value larger than 21 when `21 < (a or b) < 30`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with the second condition - `a <= 21 || b > 21`. Since you're using the logical "or" operator (`||`), this expression will evaluate as true if the first part if true, regardless of the second part. I.e., if `a` is less than 21, it will return the value of `a` **regardless** of the value of `b`. The same problem exists in third condition.

Instead of using `||`, you should use `&&`:

```
if ( a > 21 && b > 21) {
    return 0;
}
else if ( a <= 21 && b > 21){
    return a;
}
else if ( a > 21 && b <= 21){
    return b;
}
else if ( a >= b){
    return a;
}
else {
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you have `||` you want `&&`:

```
    if ( a > 21 && b > 21){
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( a <= 21 && b > 21){
        return a;
    }
    else if ( a > 21 && b <= 21){
        return b;
    }
    else if ( a >= b){
```

Without this change, you will return "a" when both a and b are < 22

Answer (score 1):

You use || (OR) where you should use && (AND) at lines `a <= 21 || b > 21` and `a > 21 || b <= 21`

NB: you already tested that the both are not >21, so you could just test: `b > 21` and `a > 21` for this two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be to sort the two numbers first. You don't need all those if statements.

```
public static int blackjack(int a, int b){
    int min = Math.min(a, b);
    int max = Math.max(a, b);
    if (max <= 21) {
        return max;
    } else {
        return min <= 21? min: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public static int blackjack(int a,int b){
      if(a>21){return (b<21)?b:0;}else{
      if(b>21){return a;}else{return (a<b)?b:a;} 
      }
      }
```

the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(blackjack(21, 21));    
      System.out.println(blackjack(28, 28));    
      System.out.println(blackjack(17, 18));    

}
```